# Laravel 5.8 - Timezone environment variable

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have a problem where I can't seem to make Laravel pick up the system wide APP_TIMEZONE env variable, I am not sure if using php-fpm affects that.

When I add it to the .env the DateTime are correctly set using the timezone
When I remove it, DateTime now uses UTC from Laravel app.php default `('timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'))`

When I remove it, add `APP_TIMEZONE` to `/etc/environment`, reboot, printenv returns the right variable so does Tinker (but I think it's using the CLI and not the FPM process) and instantiating a date in Tinker shows the correct timezone, however running my app show dates are using the default value UTC which means it didn't pick up the system wide variable (I did clear cache in every changes)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

the timezone in the config/app file appears to be set to an env() function.
this is like saying "hey go look in the .env file, see if ya got APP_TIMEZONE set. if ya don't then use UTC. thanks."

You can comment out the line in the config/app.php file and i believe the system default, in this case your environment variable, should take precedent.